# How do you determine the $\Sigma_{k=1}^∞$ $B_k$ when using the Limit comparison Test?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a question here which is asking me to determine if $\Sigma_{k=1}^∞$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2k+9}$ converges or diverges.

It asks to use the Limit comparison Test, which means I have got to determine $\Sigma_{k=1}^∞$  $B_k$ but I don't see what the technique for determining the correct one is.

I used $\Sigma_{k=1}^∞$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2k}$ which gave me p = 1.
They used $\Sigma_{k=1}^∞$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt k}$ which gave them p = 1/2.

So it clearly matters which one you choose.

Thanks!

Comment: What is $B_k$ here?

Comment: It's the second series that's used in the limit comparison test. It's not told to you, only the $A_k$ Is told and you determine the $B_k$ to go with it.

Comment: The $A_k$ being the first series in the question.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}k+9} > \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}(k+9)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+9}$ which clearly blows up! The series diverges. Game over.

Comment: You don't need the sum, you only need to know whether it's finite or not, and whether $\lim \frac{A_k}{B_k} > 0$.

Comment: I think I've written it wrong @Roronoa It is meant to be Root of the entire (2k+9).

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, but to find if the lim is >0 I need a $B_k$. This isn't given to me. I have to determine it myself and I have no technique of correctly determining that. The notes determined something different to me and ended up with a different answer.

Comment: Your choice and the notes' choice differ only by a constant nonzero factor. Constant factors don't matter for the choice. If one chooses a sequence $(B_k)$ and the other chooses $(23B_k)$, they get different values for the limit of the quotients, but one works if and only if the other works.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. Another question is, I chose my $\Sigma_{k=1}^∞$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2k}$ to be what is because I noticed that throughout the lecuture notes they chose their $B_k$ to be the $A_k$ without the constant but i'm wondering if there is a particular reason they are not adding a constant instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. Alternatively, one may notice that
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{2k+9}}\ge \frac13\left( \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)\qquad k\ge 1,
$$ then, by a telescoping sum,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{2k+9}}\ge \frac13\left( \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{1}\right)
$$the initial series is then *divergent*.

Comment: I can't do this because it specifically asks to use the Limit comparison Test but How did you get the first line anyway?

Comment: One has $\frac1{\sqrt{2k+9}}\ge\frac1{\sqrt{9k+9}}=\frac13\cdot \frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\ge \frac13\big( \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\big).$